# Showing loading image with getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to use a loading image while retrieving data through AJAX with getJSON. I have been looking around but haven't yet found a proper way of doing this. What is the best way to do this?

```
$.getJSON('file.php', function(json) {
    $.each(json, function() {

    // Retrieving data from json...

    });
});
```

Answer (score 23):

Show spinner before getJson call and then hide after response is parsed

```
 $(".someSpinnerImage").show();
    $.getJSON('file.php', function(json) {
       $.each(json, function() {
          // Retrieving data from json...

       });
       $(".someSpinnerImage").hide();  
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

you can **configure** for **global** use, it will be **internally** called whenever an **ajax** call is made.

```
$.ajaxStart(function() {
    $("img#loading").show();
});

$.ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("img#loading").hide();
});
```

Comment: Does this still work?  I dont think so.  I'm getting: $.ajaxStart is not a function

Answer (score 3):

[.ajaxStart() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) says :

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events,
>   including those added with the .ajaxStart() method, must be attached
>   to document.

If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the global option set to false, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire.

Comment: $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#loading').show();    
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
});